# Using Bubble Sort, how can I use the second element so I can print in descending order

Tags: python, sorting, bubble-sort

I was trying to use bubble sort in sorting a linked list in descending order. My code prints out a list in alphabetical order instead. I wanted to print out  the second element and sort it from highest to lowest value instead of alphabetical order.

What am I missing here? If someone can point this out, I would entirely be grateful thanks.

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.label = data[0][0]
        self.value = data[0][1]
        self.tail = None if (len(data) == 1) else LinkedList(data[1:])

countries = [("Ukraine",41879904),("Brunei",442400),("Christmas Island (Australia)",1928),("Mauritius",1265985),("Lesotho",2007201),("Guatemala",16604026),("British Virgin Islands (UK)",30030),("Malta",493559),("Greenland (Denmark)",56081),("Guernsey (UK)",62792)]


# BUBBLE SORT 
def bubbleSort(countries):
    for passnum in range(len(countries)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range (passnum):
            for j in range(0, len(countries)-i,-1)
                if (countries[j][1] > countries[j+1][1]):
                    temp = countries[j]
                    countries[j] = countries[j+1]
                    countries[j+1] = temp
        return countries

print("Bubble Sort")
print("The Unsorted List: ", countries)

print('\n' * 1)

bubbleSort(countries)
print("The Original Sorted List: ", countries)

print('\n' * 1)

countries.reverse()
print("The Updated List in Descending Order: ", countries)
```

Comment: You aren't using `LinkedList` at all in the posted code.  Are you trying to sort a *Python* list, i.e. an array, or a linked list that uses your own linked list class?

Comment: `range(0, len(countries)-i,-1)` is not going to bring you far ;-) You would have stepped through your code with a debugger, you shouldn't even have to ask this question.

Comment: Do you need to write a bubble sort implementation or do you just need the list to be sorted in any way that works?

Comment: Your attempt at a bubble sort actually implements an exchange sort (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Exchange_sort) on the Python list, not on your linked list, please clean up your question and examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bubble sort on a linked list progresses through the list swapping consecutive elements pairs that are in the wrong order, repeating the process until no more swaps are made.

You can implement it by swapping element contents or by rearranging the links.

**Swapping content**

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, data=None,*more):
        self.label, self.value = data or [None,None]
        self.link = LinkedList(*more) if more else None 
    
def bubbleSort(L):
    swapping = True
    while swapping:            # go through list as many times as needed
        swapping = False
        a,b = L,L.link         # compare successive element pairs
        while a and b:
            if a.value<b.value: # swap if in wrong order
                a.value,b.value = b.value,a.value
                a.label,b.label = b.label,a.label
                swapping = True
            a,b = b,b.link  # advance in linked list
```

Sample use:

```
countries = LinkedList(("Ukraine",41879904),("Brunei",442400),
             ("Christmas Island (Australia)",1928), ("Mauritius",1265985),
             ("Lesotho",2007201),("Guatemala",16604026),
             ("British Virgin Islands (UK)",30030),("Malta",493559),
             ("Greenland (Denmark)",56081),("Guernsey (UK)",62792))
    
print("linked list")
e = countries
while e:
    print(e.label,e.value,end=" --> ")
    e = e.link
print("END")

bubbleSort(countries)

print("sorted list")
e = countries
while e:
    print(e.label,e.value,end=" --> ")
    e = e.link
print("END")
```

Output:

```
linked list
Ukraine 41879904 --> Brunei 442400 --> Christmas Island (Australia) 1928 --> Mauritius 1265985 --> Lesotho 2007201 --> Guatemala 16604026 --> British Virgin Islands (UK) 30030 --> Malta 493559 --> Greenland (Denmark) 56081 --> Guernsey (UK) 62792 --> END
sorted list
Ukraine 41879904 --> Guatemala 16604026 --> Lesotho 2007201 --> Mauritius 1265985 --> Malta 493559 --> Brunei 442400 --> Guernsey (UK) 62792 --> Greenland (Denmark) 56081 --> British Virgin Islands (UK) 30030 --> Christmas Island (Australia) 1928 --> END
```

**Rearranging links**

A bubble sort that manipulates the links will need to return a new head because the original one may no longer be first in the list after sorting:

```
def bubbleSort(L):
    head      = LinkedList() # need pointer to head
    head.link = L            # to track if it is swapped
    swapping  = True
    while swapping:          # go through list as many times as needed
        swapping = False
        prev,a,b = head,L,L.link # process needs predecessor of a
        while a and b:
            if a.value<b.value: # swap if in wrong order
                prev.link,b.link,a.link = b,a,b.link # rearrange links
                prev,a,b = b,a,a.link                # avance through list
                swapping = True
            else:
                prev,a,b = a,b,b.link                # avance through list
    return head.link                                 # return new head
```

Usage:

```
countries = LinkedList(("Ukraine",41879904),("Brunei",442400),
             ("Christmas Island (Australia)",1928), ("Mauritius",1265985),
             ("Lesotho",2007201),("Guatemala",16604026),
             ("British Virgin Islands (UK)",30030),("Malta",493559),
             ("Greenland (Denmark)",56081),("Guernsey (UK)",62792))

countries = bubbleSort(countries)  # returns new head of the (sorted) list
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I will be trying this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you require three nested loops or if the `passnum` variable has any relevance. I haven't included that in this answer but if it's important the change wouldn't make any difference.

```
def bubbleSort(countries):
    for i in range(len(countries)):
        for j in range(0, len(countries)-i-1):
            if countries[j][1] > countries[j+1][1]:
                temp = countries[j]
                countries[j] = countries[j+1]
                countries[j+1] = temp
    return countries
```

**Output**

```
Bubble Sort
The Unsorted List:  [('Ukraine', 41879904), ('Brunei', 442400), ('Christmas Island (Australia)', 1928), ('Mauritius', 1265985), ('Lesotho', 2007201), ('Guatemala', 16604026), ('British Virgin Islands (UK)', 30030), ('Malta', 493559), ('Greenland (Denmark)', 56081), ('Guernsey (UK)', 62792)] 


The Original Sorted List:  [('Christmas Island (Australia)', 1928), ('British Virgin Islands (UK)', 30030), ('Greenland (Denmark)', 56081), ('Guernsey (UK)', 62792), ('Brunei', 442400), ('Malta', 493559), ('Mauritius', 1265985), ('Lesotho', 2007201), ('Guatemala', 16604026), ('Ukraine', 41879904)]


The Updated List in Descending Order:  [('Ukraine', 41879904), ('Guatemala', 16604026), ('Lesotho', 2007201), ('Mauritius', 1265985), ('Malta', 493559), ('Brunei', 442400), ('Guernsey (UK)', 62792), ('Greenland (Denmark)', 56081), ('British Virgin Islands (UK)', 30030), ('Christmas Island (Australia)', 1928)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has a built in sorting function, that will probably be faster than a self coded version of Bubble Sort.

This code:

```
temp = [("ukraine", 852), ("America", 965), ("China", 785)]

nums = [i[1] for i in temp]
nums.sort(reverse=True)
ordered = []
for num in nums:
    for item in temp:
        if num == item[1]:
            ordered.append(item)
```

returns a sorted list, in descending order.
Is using bubble sort required, or did you just pick it as a sorting algorithm?

As pointed out by Jasmijn, this isn't terribly efficient, and doesn't handle the complete field of possibility with the data.

This code:

```
temp = [("ukraine", 852), ("America", 965), ("China", 785), ("Argentina", 965)]
temp.sort(key=lambda a: a[1], reverse=True)
```

handles all possibilities within the data, is more concise, and more efficient than my first code snippit.

Comment: This won't work if any two or more items have the same value, and also takes O(n²) instead of O(n log(n)).

Comment: @Jasmijn Thank you for pointing that out! I'd love to hear your feedback on the proposed fix.

Comment: That should solve it!

Comment: Using bubble sort is not required, but by far the one that I've chosen. I'm also open in trying other sorting algorithms so I can better understand how sorting goes in python. Thank you very much for this.

Comment: Thank you I will try this too. I'm in the process of learning different sorting algorithms in python.